# WCF service to queue all request

Tags: wcf, msmq, netmsmqbinding

I have a wcf service and handle a lot of client (server document generation). This service should receive a lot of request and should be handle in queue. It also have a callback. (callback will return successfully generated document). I am still using PIA and will implement OpenXML in the future.

Is it wcf msmq is the way to implement this?

Is there any samples might be related? Previously its running in local machine but now want to change it as a so called "Server generated"

Answer (score 1):

WCF MSMQ doesn't support callback directly - it supports only one-way operations. But for example [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/duplexmsmq.aspx) discuss how to add this support. With default configuration you can send message back to original sender but it is not a callback. To support responses every client will have to expose queue and pass address of its queue as part of the request to be able to receive the message from the service. More about responses in MSMQ is in [MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163482.aspx).

Comment: Thanks.. will look into that. Still learn about msmq binding. other binding seem easy but msmq need some time to configure.